# Custom Loop with profile user

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a profile page setup that shows profile user's information.

The URL is as following:

- User 1 ("Steve" User ID: 10): `http://example.com/?page_id=10&up_username=Steve`
- User 2 ("Ryan" User ID: 35 ): `http://example.com/?page_id=10&up_username=Ryan`

Now, I have a custom post loop to show posts uploaded by the individual users as following:

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {

        $paged = get_query_var('paged');

    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {

        $paged = get_query_var('page');

    } else {

        $paged = 1;

    }

    $args = array(          
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'product_cat' => '',
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'author' => ''
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    global $product, $userpro, $post, $paged ; 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>
```

Here, the `author` arg is empty. So it loads posts by the author (which is admin). Regardless of which profile page you are in, it will only show the admin's post.

**Scenario: Ryan's post (user id= 35)**

```
 'author' => '35'
```

If I put `35` as the author, then it will only show Ryan's posts, regardless of which profile you are view.

However, here is a profile page title that I have which shows "Actual" profile user.

```
<?php echo userpro_profile_data('display_name', $user_id); ?>
```

With the above, it will actually display the profile user and not `'author' => '35'`.

How can I change the `'author'` section in the custom loop so that it will display the profile user posts?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Here is the new code based on @Nathan Dawson answer:

```
     <div class="rfp_hide" id="rhm_profile_item">
    <?php
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }       
    // Default to false in case user can't be found.
    $user_id  = false;
    // Clean username variable before use.
    $username = ( ! empty( $_GET['up_username'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['up_username'] ) : false;
    // Check for user ID.
    if ( $username && $user = get_user_by( 'slug', $username ) ) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
    }   
    $args = array(      
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC',  
    );
    if ( $user_id ) {
        $args['author'] = $user_id;
    }       
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    global $userpro, $post, $paged, $user_id ; 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <div class="rhm_container">
        Post contents goes here  
    </div>      
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   

    </div>
```

Comment: How are you getting `$user_id` at this point? And is that the current_user or the profile user's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is get the WordPress user ID from the username in the query string.

```
// Default to false in case user can't be found.
$user_id  = false;

// Clean username variable before use.
$username = ( ! empty( $_GET['up_username'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['up_username'] ) : false;

// Check for user ID.
if ( $username && $user = get_user_by( 'slug', $username ) ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
}
```

Once you have the ID you can add it to the list of arguments for WP_Query.

Take the author parameter out of the arguments array and check you have a user ID before adding it.

```
$args = array(          
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'product_cat'    => '',
    'orderby'        => 'date',            
    'order'          => 'DESC',
);

if ( $user_id ) {
    $args['author'] = $user_id;
}

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated the code with what I have now. It is still giving me the page author (admin) posts instead of the profile user. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.. =(

Comment: @EmilyTurcato start `echo`ing out your variables along the way, particularly `$username` and `$user_id`. Something is missing.